# Typical high amperage applicance power cord age

Tags: dryer, appliances, stove, range

This question on high amperage/power cords used with appliances such as dryers and ranges. I am curious to know typically how long these cords are good for. 5 years? 10 years? 20 years? 40 years?

I know they're expected to last at least 3 years because Home Depot in the US tells me this product http://www.homedepot.com/p/GE-4-ft-4-Prong-40-Amp-Range-Cord-WX09X10035DS/203438714 has some kind of 3-year extended warranty I can get.

I saw [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/53467/is-there-a-good-reason-not-to-reuse-the-power-cord-when-replacing-my-electric-ra) and it seems 40-60 years is pushing it.

Comment: Keep in mind that H*#e De*&t's extended warranties are just insurance policies, they have no actual bearing on the quality or life expectancy of anything they sell.

Comment: I just bought one of those, skipped the waste of dollars warranty (manufactures is 1YR), if it does not fail in a few minutes or the first year of use it likely will work for many years unless your constantly moving the range or dryer.

Comment: Just what I said in that answer about the inherently hazardous NEMA 10.  And old cord can be either pretty janky or in fine condition depending on whether it's been exposed (e.g. heat or food splash) or sheltered (e.g. from UV damage). The warranties are flimflam - they'd happily sell you a warranty on a 10-24 nut.  The purpose of bigbos is to separate you from your money.  If you want a competent retailer who cares, shop at a real electrical supply.

Comment: Anecdotally, the cord on my 1970's range was just fine ~45 years later when the oven element blew and it was replaced (cheaper to get a used newer stove than a new oven element, and it was starting to display some other questionable behavior that would have involved more parts/expense.)

Answer (score 1):

The conditions the cord is exposed to will affect the life of the insulation, high heat and light exposure are 2 things that age insulation. If the cord is still flexible and there are no cracks it should be fine. I had a dryer that I kept going for 20+ years that the cord was still in good shape but, when I updated the wiring to a 4 wire receptacle, the 3 wire cord had to go.